# Finding a+b+c+d where a,b and c,d are the roots of two different quadratic equations

Tags: quadratics

If $a, b$ are the roots of the equation $x^2-10cx-11d=0$ and $c,d$ are the roots of the equation $x^2-10ax-11b=0$ (where $a\ne b\ne c\ne d\ne 0$), then find the value of $a+b+c+d$.

I have the following data:

- $a+b=10c$
- $c+d=10a$
- $ab=-11d$
- $cd=-11b$
- $\frac{c-a}{b-d}=\frac1 {11}$

Comment: Facts 3&4 let you conclude that $ac=121$.

Comment: @vadim123 with some additional *please-dont-be-zero* work

Comment: What is interesting is that they gave you the fifth data. In principle, there are four unknwowns then four equations (data) should be sufficient. In your opinion, what is the role of the fifth data ?

Comment: As the equations aren't linear, it's possible that four equations are not enough.

Comment: @Doc. Four equations for four unknowns have solutions (multiple, may be).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, that is the data which I have evaluated. They have given only the equations.

Comment: @Claude, of course you are correct.  I meant that four equations may not be enough to determine a _unique_ solution.  It's clear that my phrasing was very poor.

Comment: @Doc. This is why they gave the fifth relation; it ensures unicity.

Comment: @Claude, but it doesn't.  The fifth relation is derived directy from the first two relations.  Thus there are multiple solutions to the system of five relations if and only if there are multiple relations to the first four.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only $c\neq a$ is needed, as shown below.

Let $p=10$ and $q=11$. Then we have

$$
x^2-pcx-qd=(x-a)(x-b) \\ x^2-pax-qb=(x-c)(x-d) \tag{1}
$$

so that

$$
a+b=pc, ab=-qd, c+d=pa, cd=-q \tag{2}
$$

We deduce that

$$
b=pc-a, d=pa-c \tag{3}
$$

so that (2) gives $a(pc-a)=-q(pa-c)$ and $c(pa-c)=-q(pc-a)$, and hence

$$
a^2=(pq)a-(q)c+(p)ac,\\ c^2=(pq)c-(q)a+(p)ac \tag{4}
$$

Substracting, we see that $c^2-a^2=(pq)(c-a)+q(c-a)$ and hence
$a+c=pq+q=q(p+1)$. Finally we have

$$
a+b+c+d=a+c+(pc-a)+(pa-c)=p(a+c)=p(p+1)q
$$

In your example, one obtains $a+b+c+d=10\times 11 \times 11=1210$.